# When can two questions be in the same question?

Tags: discussion, appropriate-questions, questions

[What do “socially imposed judgments” and “Keyboard, face, keyboard, face.” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29617/what-do-socially-imposed-judgments-and-keyboard-face-keyboard-face-mean)

The differing opinion here seems to revolve around the idea that the two questions are coming from the same source. The asker didn't know what two phrases meant and decided to ask us.

Should EL&U enforce a one question per question policy even if more than one question relevant to the topic?

Comment: Related: Five questions in one: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20247/expressions-in-tim-minchins-storm

Answer (score 4):

My opinion on this subject is (again) the stricter one. Questions should have one question for the following reasons:

- Answers should only have to juggle one question at a time
- Answers with more than one answer could be both right and wrong, causing confusion on behalf of the voters
- Jamming two questions into one title can be excessive
- One question could be closable but the other isn't
- One question could be extremely interesting and deserve scores of upvotes... but the other isn't
- If the restriction isn't *one*, what is it? *Two*?
- How are people who have poor judgement supposed to understand when it is okay to ask two-in-one? Avoiding drama by restricting it to one-per-one is good.

Comment: Yes, one question at a time, but the OP may not be aware that they're separate. Is it possible to split questions, that is, have the OP edit and resubmit the second part, linking to the first?

Comment: I think your arguments are absolutely reasonable. Ideally this should have been two questions. But I don't think this kind of double interpretation questions aren't really much of a problem in practice; so wouldn't closure be a bit of a sledgehammer? In addition, I think the fact that the OP cannot always *know* that they are unrelated should count for something, as the others say. Lastly, the problem solves itself in most cases: if a certain answer has 1 right 1 wrong, someone else will feel compelled to post an answer with both right eventually (or someone edits his old half-right answer).

Comment: This and only this.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good question and worth discussing.  However, in the example question, I think the OP did not know that the two questions were unrelated, and thought that the phrases had something to do with each other (in which case it makes sense to ask about them together).

I agree that there should be only one primary question, but argue that it can make sense to have related questions as well.  Although one answer can be right and wrong, we can have this problem with just [one question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28687/what-does-lower-oneself-for-farewell-swim-mean-is-this-a-sport-related-jargon) anyway.

Finally, how do we determine what one question is, particularly when a user might ask for the correct choice amongst several valid alternatives?  Should that person then ask one question for each possible pair of alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

When the two questions are unrelated they should be separate, when they are interdependent then it's fine.  It is judgement of course but I think it's reasonable to expect that from users.

I give people feedback about how well their question is structured by using my downvote finger or making a constructive comment.

FWIW I think the question in question should be separate in an ideal world but there are way, way worse questions out there.